# Android - Google Image Search API?

Tags: android

Hi I have been using Google Image Search API in my Android apps, and I also know that this API is deprecated and it will be shut down someday, I don't understand and can't find full information why do they shutting down this API?

**Why this API is deprecated ?**

**Is there any other image search APIs that I can use in my android apps ?**

Thanks

Comment: And for the question why it is deprecated. Originally it was made open(free) so that people can come up with innovative ideas, instead it is being used by many for data mining which is hurting Google servers. This reason was mentioned somewhere in their blog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the [Bing Image Search API](http://martinsikora.com/bing-image-search-api)

So, for example if you're looking for pictures of Prague, your URL might look like this:

http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?AppId=5B0D22D739247C06BE7F990ECBEC1A144F9B7C39&Sources=image&Query=prague&Image.Count=3&Image.Offset=0&Image.Filters=Size:Medium

Comment: What about search by image itself, not by metadata or keywords?

Comment: How can we increase the limit from 8 to more images that we want?